# Selenium IDE no longer compatible with Firefox 18?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I've been using the Selenium IDE for a while now in Firefox, but lately Firefox has 'upgraded' itself to V18 - and now I can't find the IDE anywhere in the menu system. I tried installing the Selenium IDE Button which should show up on the toolbar but that is conspicuous by its absence too.

I know I have selenium installed on this machine because my existing tests work (exported to C# and using MSTest), but I can no longer conveniently create new ones using the IDE as a recorder, which is a drag.

Has the latest Firefox broken Selenium IDE?

Comment: Well what does it say in the Addons list, does it say it's disabled?

Comment: I see my FF is now 19  (and no IDE as well (obviously), it is showing as enabled. I use to rely on Selenium a few years ago, time to find an alternative I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced the same thing when trying to run Selenium tests in Java with the WebDriver, so I had to downgrade Firefox to an older version.

Based on their release note I guess the IDE would only support up to version 17 as of now:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes

Comment: It's not just the IDE. Some functions/methods in Selenium don't work properly in Firefox 18.

Comment: @RobH I'd need you to back that statement up with some data, because it's a pretty big accusation to level. Bear in mind that some things with Selenium may get broken with new Firefox releases, but they are usually cleared up within a few days with a subsequent Selenium release.

Comment: I've rolled back to FF15, and it seems broken in FF15 too. My big question now is how do I get hold of the Selenium IDE 1.10.0? That is claimed (in the release notes) to be working with FF17. All I want is so be able to use a selenium IDE to record test scripts, as I have been doing for the last few years until FF upgraded itself to 18.

Comment: Ok found that and it is now available in my FF. One thing I can't seem to suprress is the auto-upgrading of FF, which seems to be the root cause of my problem. This is a work issue and I can't afford to have things suddenly break on me because FF has decided to upgrade itself..

Comment: @haughtonomous: Go to Options->Advanced. You'll see the upgrade options right there. You can let it check for upgrades but let you choose whether or not to install them, or you can have it never check for upgrades. (I have it set to the former, and since I downgraded to FF 17, it's only been giving me later builds of 17, rather than making me go to 18 again.)

Comment: @JimEvans: I don't know the exact details, but some of my colleagues have reported problems with some of the Webdriver functions not working properly with FF 18, which is why those of us who are working with Selenium have all downgraded FF back to 17.

Comment: @RobH The WebDriver developers can't fix what they don't know is broken. There is a suite of some 600 tests that run with every commit to the project, and they execute on no less than four versions of Firefox (as well as 5 versions of IE, one of Chrome, and several of Opera). The project does not release without performing some level of testing. So please forgive my lack of enthusiasm for vague pronouncements that "some things don't work." Surely, you can see how that's less than helpful

Comment: Well now, this is bizarre. It's why I like computers - I never know what is going to happen next. I 'downgraded' to FF17, installed the IDE again, and behind my back (before I got to stop it) it had upgraded itself to 19 again. But oila! the selenium IDE is now working. Am I senile? (well yes, but is it now becoming obvious?) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have Selenium IDE working in FF 19 !

1. I did not see the IDE button in FF 19 to launch it, even though it was indeed enabled (perhaps it was there and I did not notice it)
2. I downloaded and installed  FF 17 (to another directory on disk) and then I happen to see it under FireFox--> Web Developer --> Selenium IDE  ...
3. I closed the FF 17 and opened FF 19 , and it was there as well, not sure if it was there all along or not.

   ```
   To launch it , just do  Ctrl + Alt + S  as this shortcut works in FF 19 too.
   ```

update:   FF 19.0.2 is working as well.  Just in case, I did also grab the:

```
"Download version under development unreleased" http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the icon appears when the toolbar is set to 'icons and text' or when the 'small icons' box is ticked, but the icon is blank when 'icons only' is selected and 'small icons' is not.

This is firefox 24.0 and selenium 2.4.0, on Windows 7, but I suspect it happens for most people.

Here's the issue in the Selenium support database:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5712